# How to access permissionSet object permission

Tags: apex, soql

I have tried few different way and I'm not getting what I want so basically I'm after finding out what object permission a permissionSet has for the object.

As you can see the attach screen shot and I'm trying to retrieve `PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsCreate, PermissionsDelete` whether its `true/false`

[image]

I run this query but even though I turn off `PermissionsDelete` I still see it to be `true` and I think I'm not querying the right way.

First run this query:

`SELECT Id from Profile where Name = 'Custom: Support profile'`

Query based off the profile:

`SELECT Id from PermissionSet where ProfileId = '00e6A000000zNUhQAM'`

`SELECT Id, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsCreate, PermissionsDelete from ObjectPermissions where ParentId = '0PS6A000000sADfWAM'  and SObjectType = 'Account'`

I'm after finding out what permissionSet(account delete) object permission has.

Comment: You have Delete set to True on your screenshot. And it returned correct value for my Profile when I followed your instructions

Comment: yes but if I turn off and save it and run the above query I still see the `true` hope you understand my question.

Comment: I did understand your question. So, on a screenshot you have 'account delete' `Permission Set`, so your query should be `SELECT Id from PermissionSet where Name = 'account delete'`. In addition, if you want for the users assigned to the `Profile` 'Custom: Support profile' and 'account delete' `Permission Set` to do not able to delete `Account` records it has to be unchecked for BOTH

Comment: yes I did tried exactly `SELECT Id from PermissionSet where Name = 'account_delete'` but there is NO field named `PermissionsDelete` in the PermissionSet.

Comment: you have to plug in returned `Permission Set` Id into this query: SELECT Id, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsCreate, PermissionsDelete from ObjectPermissions where ParentId = 'yourPermissionSetId'  and SObjectType = 'Account'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run query to find out what Permission Set Id is:

`SELECT Id from PermissionSet where Label = 'account delete'`

Then plug in returned Permission Set Id into this query:

`SELECT Id, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsCreate, PermissionsDelete from ObjectPermissions where ParentId = 'yourPermissionSetId' and SObjectType = 'Account'`

If you want for the users assigned to the Profile 'Custom: Support profile' and 'account delete' Permission Set to do not able to delete Account records, it has to be unchecked for BOTH